# Differences between using numpy append or array append - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have this basic example to understand the numpy append method.

```
distances=[]
for i in range (8):
    distances = np.append(distances, (i))
print(distances)

distances=[]
for i in range (8):
    distances.append(i)
print(distances)
```

The output gives me 2 arrays but are in different format (or what I understand of different format).

```
[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

What is the exact different of both arrays and why is the output different?

Comment: One is a numpy array containing floats, the other is a list of integers

Comment: But why does one contain floats and why integers. And why one is an array and the other one is a list, if I am doing the same thing? And `i`is the same for both, I do not understand why one would be floats and the other one ints.@DavidG

Comment: Floats are the default type for numpy arrays.

Comment: What do you mean "doing the same thing"? You are not. The first gives you an array and is the result of array methods, the second produces a list and is a result of list methods.

Comment: `np.append` is a numpy function that is named like the list `append`, but is a poor replica.  I discourage using it.  It gives beginners too many problems (like 4-5 SO questions in the last couple of days).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second method is pure python and doesn't use any numpy, so the type starts as list (`[]`) and stays that way, because `list.append()` leaves `list` as a list. It contains integers because that's what you get out of `range` and nothing in your code changes them.

The first method uses numpy's [`append` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) that returns an ndarray, which uses floats by default. This also explains why your returned array contains floats.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `list.append()` returns None, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

The first code

```
distances=[]
for i in range (8):
    distances = np.append(distances, (i))
print(distances)
```

results in `distances` being an [`array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy-array) of [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)s. While the second code

```
distances=[]
for i in range (8):
    distances.append(i)
print(distances)
```

results in `distances` being a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) of [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)s.

`arrary` is a numpy type (main difference: faster, all items have the same type), while `list` is python-internal (main difference: works without `numpy`, can hold any mixed types).

Answer (score 1):

The first gives you an `numpy.ndarray` and is the result of `numpy` methods, the second produces a `list` and is a result of `list` methods. Numpy arrays and Python lists are not the same thing.

Numpy arrays are essentially object-oriented wrappers around fix-sized, typed, true multidimensional arrays. `numpy` array methods are optimized for vectorized numerical calculations, and along with `scipy`, provide powerful scientific computing and linear algebra capabilities.

Python `list` objects are heterogeneous, resizable, array-lists. They are optimized for constant-time `.append`. Indeed, both of these for-loops will scale very differently. `numpy.ndarray.append` requires creating an entirely new array each iteration. Python `list` have amoratized constant time append. Thus, you will see quadratic growth in runtime as the size of your `numpy.ndarray` scales, whereas with the list, you will see linear scaling.